# Do I need this code for the Facebook Like box to work?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to clean up some code that a friend helped me with a while back, and I ran across a text widget that displays my Facebook Like box. I've pasted the code below. Do I need all of this code? When I go to Facebook and try set up the Like Box from scratch, it does not have the  . I didn't know what that was for, and if I needed it. Also should I have the  in the text widget or put that in the header.php file ?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/noahsdadcom" data-width="300" data-colorscheme="dark" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need all this code for facebook likebox to work. 
Also, dont try to clean, unless you know `alot` about that language (experience ;) )

Comment: When I go to Facebook and create the Facebook like box it says to add the <div id="fb-root"></div> to the header and then just the <div class="fb-like-box" data" Why does it not mention that <script>?

Comment: See the first point (when you click `get code` while creating like-box),

Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening `<body>` tag. This is that javascript SDK.

Comment: Ok, so would you still leave all of that in the text widget? What if I want to use some of the other social features of Facebook? Does that one instance work for everything, even inside of a widget?

Comment: You need to add javascript sdk for one time only . After that you can use any facebook social plugin with their respective codes :)

If I help you, mark as answer.

Comment: but if it's in a widget won't it just effect that widget? If that widget isn't on a certain page?

Comment: Only this code `<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/noahsdadcom" data-width="300" data-colorscheme="dark" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>` is responsible for likebox. The code above it is same for all social plugins. You can use any no of social plugins . They wont interfere with each other :)

Comment: No, I get that. But ALL of that code I posted above it in a text widget box. So if there was a page with no sidebar that <script> wouldn't load, and the other social plug in wouldn't work, right? I'm not sure if I'm being clear. I'm asking 1. do i need the code? 2. Should all of that code be in the text widget or elsewhere?

Comment: So if there was a page with no sidebar, it wont work. Right. You need to place it wherever you need it. Put it just after the opening `body` tag as suggested by facebook.

Comment: that what I was saying all along. Should I just put the <div class="fb-like-box" in the text widget and put these two (<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {) elsewhere? I'm using a child theme, so shoudl I put this in a child theme header.php?

Comment: You can them together or apart. Just keep in mind , the first two codes should come before the `<div class=fb-like-box`but after the starting `body` tag. Why dont you try some code at your own ? If you fail, ask again :) And mark question as answer ;)

Comment: thanks. I will mark the question as answered as soon as I understand the answer. :) So do I take both of those codes and put it in my header.php file? If so how does that work if you're using a child theme?

Comment: First atleast try it. It that doesnt work, ask again. If you are asking about wp child theme, its nothing but a separate css and functions file. So, there wont be any difference.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my question. I want to try it, but in my child theme I only have a styles.css. Do I need to duplicate the header.php file that's in the parent theme and put it in the child theme?

Comment: First, this is another question. Second child theme doesnt have header.php. Either use code in main theme or a better approach would be creating a hook on functions.php of child theme. See this for help, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43672/how-to-add-code-to-header-php-in-a-child-theme

Comment: I'm not sure why this is a 2nd question. I was asking if that code needs to be in the text widget or elsewhere.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11463/discussion-between-jashwant-and-rick-smith)

Comment: I added the code like You said in that link, but it's going into the header, not the body.

Comment: If you look down on the `header.php` file, you will see `body` tag there. Place it after that :)

Comment: But you told me to put it in that plugin hook....there is nothing that says body in there.